# Как сделать запрос сразу с действием над датой в БД (MySQL)?

Tags: sql, mysqli

В Wordpress есть таблица xx_postmeta. Данные там пишутся в 4 поля: meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value. 
И вот для одной записи в эту таблицу пишется много данных. У всех одинаковый post_id. И в этой же таблице есть значение с датой события (meta_key = 'date_st'). И есть период, указывающий на количество дней от этой даты (meta_key = recurrence_days).

Можно ли SQL запросом выбрать данные и сразу проверить, входит ли текущий день в срок между датой date_st и датой date_st + recurrence_days? Т.е. логически в самом запросе нужно сразу выбрать дату, выбрать период, а потом сверить попадание текущего дня в термин от даты старта до даты старта + период из базы. Это возможно?

Пример: 
date_st = 2018-09-22
recurrence_days = 40 (т.е. конец периода - 2018-11-01)

Comment: Можно, но непонятно что вы хотите именно в условии where - можно комбинировать условия как вам пожелается. простите за тавтологию. `where (date_st = 2018-09-22) and (recurrence_days = 40)`

Comment: Дополню комментарий, возможно вы о таком хотели спросить? 
`where (date_st = 2018-09-22) and (date_st+recurrence_days > 2018-09-22+40)` собственно ответ такой же - можно и так... так что формулируйте вопрос ясней и вполне возможно что этого добиться совсем не сложно

Comment: В условии Where я хочу проверить, попадает ли текущий день (когда происходит операция) между датами старта и датой конца (при этом, дата конца = дата старта + период. Дата старта и период - в одной таблице). 
И еще сложность: все это идет с условием по post_id - т.е. для конкретного post_id.

Comment: Я всеравно мало чего понял, но в комментарии выше есть примеры того что это реализуемо =) вы можете складывать умножать делить и т.д. любые выбиремые поля, и делать это в том числе в фильтре, так же можете комбинировать условия or\not\and и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то вроде:

```
select *
  from xx_postmeta p1
  join xx_postmeta p2 on p2.post_id=p1.post_id and p2.meta_key='recurrence_days'
 where p1.meta_key='date_st'
   and now() between p1.meta_value and p1.meta_value + interval p2.meta_value day
```

Так как вы не привели текста для создания тестовой таблицы с данными, то запрос не проверялся и могут быть разнообразные нюансы в зависимости от состава информации, которую вы хотите получить и формата даты в meta_value.

Comment: никогда бы так не интерпретировал вопрос =) у вас талант читать такие "просьбы" =)

Comment: Спасибо! Буду внедрять.